# Exception Error while loading data from response in Custom Table View Controller in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Made a custom table view controller in which call a service in viewDidLoad method. The service is called with some parameters and it is GET request. The response is coming fine but it is showing an exception error this,Terminating app due to uncaught exception

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x60000036a140> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key data.'

My response from service is this

`{"data":[{"id":"139559","first_name":"Shoaib Anwar","last_name":null,"address":null,"mobile":"03233008757","city":null,"date":"2017-08-10","date_of_birth":"1992-08-10"}]}.`

The app crashes all the time , i'm confused why it is showing this error.

My code is this,

```
    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"number"];
    NSString *url=@"My Url";
    NSString *string3 = [url stringByAppendingString:savedValue];

    NSString *lastArray = @"&type=json";
    string3 = [string3 stringByAppendingString:lastArray];
    NSLog(@"Mmm %@",savedValue);
    NSLog(@"Mmm %@",string3);

    NSString *targetUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string3];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetUrl]];

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
      ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
        NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
        NSError * _Nullable error) {

          NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSLog(@"Data received: %@", myString);
          NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                 error:nil];
          NSString *value = json[@"data"];



     _Ids = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in value)
    {
        // Create a new Customer record

        ViewProfile * newCustomer = [[ViewProfile alloc] init];



        newCustomer.ids = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", newCustomer.ids);

        newCustomer.fname = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"first_name"];
        NSLog(@"Fname: %@ ", newCustomer.fname);

        newCustomer.lname = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"last_name"];

        NSLog(@"Lname: %@ ", newCustomer.lname);

        newCustomer.address = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"address"];
        NSLog(@"Address: %@ ", newCustomer.address);

        newCustomer.mobile = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"mobile"];
        NSLog(@"Mobile: %@ ", newCustomer.mobile);

        newCustomer.city = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"city"];
        NSLog(@"City: %@ ", newCustomer.city);

        newCustomer.date = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSLog(@"Date: %@ ", newCustomer.date);

        newCustomer.dob = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"date_of_birth"];
        NSLog(@"DOB: %@ ", newCustomer.dob);

        // Add our new Customer record to our NSMutableArray
        [_Ids addObject:newCustomer];

    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // This code will run once the JSON-loading section above has completed.

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });




    NSString *status=[myString valueForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Status:%@",status);




 }] resume];
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: check it. @NaumanMalik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is a json string.

Try to convert myString property to NSData type and then pass to NSJsonSerialisation class.

```
NSData *jsonData =   [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: now getting this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000000617461644'. @Basheer

Comment: @Oneeb  NSString *value = json[@"data"];   json[@"data"] will return array. But why you are assigning to NSString?

Comment: than what to write? @Basheer

Comment: Change NSString to NSArray.

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you should comment this line

```
NSString *status=[myString valueForKey:@"data"];
```

or check your storyboard or Xib

are you have Label or Button like the image attached

[image]

Comment: every thing is correct  no such outlet issues. @Abdelahad Darwish

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and update according to your requirement.

```
NSString *myString = @"{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"139559\",\"first_name\":\"Shoaib Anwar\",\"last_name\":null,\"address\":null,\"mobile\":\"03233008757\",\"city\":null,\"date\":\"2017-08-10\",\"date_of_birth\":\"1992-08-10\"}]}";

NSData *data =  [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSArray *value = json[@"data"];

for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in value)
{
    // Create a new Customer record

    NSLog(@"ID: %@ ", [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"Fname: %@ ", [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"first_name"]);
}
```

Crashing issue because of `NSString *status=[myString valueForKey:@"data"];`

Comment: Thanks i got my answer.:) @Neha Gupta